# Check if VPN exist in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how to check if my VPN connection is active.

With this code i see all my networks connection

```
Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
    If nics.Length < 0 Or nics Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No NICS")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nics
        Dim intproperties As IPInterfaceProperties = netadapter.GetIPProperties()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(netadapter.Name)
    Next
```

When my vpn connection is active i see in that list "VPN"

How can i check if there is no "VPN" in that list or even without ListBox?

Comment: In your `For Each` loop, add something like `If netadapter.Name.ToUpper.IndexOf("VPN") > -1 Then MessageBox.Show("VPN active")` in place of adding to the ListBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) query for that task:

```
Dim isVpnExist As Boolean = nics.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x.Name = "VPN")
If isVpnExist = True Then
    ' vpn exist do something
Else
    ' vpn is not exist do something
End If
```